# Joomla rest api issue

Tags: php, joomla

I have installed com api and users plugin from Techjoomla.
I try to connect:

```
MyDomain/index.php?option=com_api&app=users&format=raw&resource=loginkey=MyKey
```

But browser respond: could not get any respond
Request log is empty. 
Apache2 log: http://prntscr.com/bq1ytu
Error after switching on Debug: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class JDispatcher in mydomain\libraries\joomla\event\dispatcher.php on line 281
Please help me to connect correctly.

And when I change the com_api/libraries/plugin.php:58

```
//$dispatcher = JEventDispatcher::getInstance();
$dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();
```

I see response in browser:

```
{"code":400,"message":"Users API Plugin not found, Users is probably not installed"}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Would it not be a smarter idea to contact the guys who developed the plugin for them to fix it?

Comment: They do not respond yet, I think maybe someone already encountered with the problem

Comment: This is for Joomla 2.5

Answer (score 0):

Problem had been solved after upgrading to joomla 3

Answer (score 0):

You must comment this line `"self::$plg_path = self::$plg_path.$plugin->name.'/';"`.

```
if (version_compare(JVERSION, '3.0', 'ge'))
{
    $dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();
}
else
{
    // $dispatcher = JEventDispatcher::getInstance();
    $dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();
    // self::$plg_path = self::$plg_path.$plugin->name.'/';
}
```

It's works fine for me. ;)
Testing under Joomla 2.5.13.